# How to convert a character vector to numeric?

Tags: r, numeric, r-factor

I have this character vector but I need to convert this to numeric.

```
>iono_test_y
[1] "g" "b" "b" "g" "g" "g" "b" "g" "b" "b" "g" "b" "g" "b" "b" "b" "g" "g" "b" "b" "b" "g" "g"
[24] "b" "b" "g" "g" "g" "b" "g" "g" "g" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "b" "g" "b" "b"
[47] "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g" "g"
[70] "g" "g"
```

I already tried

```
iono_test_y <- as.numeric(as.character(iono_test_y)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. How can I do that?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character())` works really well when you have a number that happens to be a factor, e.g., `x = factor(2012:2017)`. You've got a bunch of letters, and R doesn't know how you want to letters into numbers (and neither do we).

Comment: It looks like your 'already tried this' is missing a paren

Comment: Try `iono_test_y <- as.numeric(iono_test_y)` without the `as.character`

Comment: @RonakShah 0 or 1, I guess....

Comment: @G5W I get this [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: @BrunoCamarda  then I doubt that `iono_test_y` is actually a factor.  Try `class(iono_test_y)`

Comment: @BrunoCamarda Do you need `as.numeric(iono_test_y == "b")` ? or vice-versa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that your variable is just a character vector,  not a factor.  You can give it a numeric encoding by using

```
as.numeric(factor(iono_test_y))
```

Comment: YES! Thank you a lot! :3

Comment: @G5W I tried this with my vector and worked fine, except the numbering is not in any specific order. eg: I expect them to go by order of the unique names, say c("a", "b", "b", "c", "d") to be converted to c(1,2,2,3,4) but what I get is on the line of c(2,4,4,3,1). Any solution for this?

Comment: @DanielPardejo   The result _is_ in a specific order,  the order that the values occurred in the data.  If you want to sort them, just use `sort`  - i.e. `sort(as.numeric(factor(iono_test_y)))`